# Abstract domain class and tablePerHierarchy

Tags: grails, gorm-mongodb

In my Grails 3.2.6 app I have 2 classes:

```
abstract class Base {
  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
  }    
}
```

and

```
class Child extends Base {
  static mapping = {
    collection 'child'
  }
}
```

Upon saving the instances of Child are dumped into "base" collection (with `_class = Child` field) instead of "child".

How to make it work right?

UPDATE

I defined the `Base` as a `trait` under `src/main/groovy`:

```
trait Base { }
```

and

```
class Child implements Base { }
```

then it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your Child class mapping method, add this

```
table "child"
```

Comment: Is ignored by gorm mongo, as well as collection for this case